# CSSRuleList traversing, Error not iterable

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

```
for(var ss of document.styleSheets){  
  for(var cssrule of ss.cssRules){continue;}}
```

document.styleSheets is of type StyleSheetList, it has a [Symbol.iterator] so it is iterable. It is populated by a number of CSSStyleSheet objects that have a cssRules property pointing to a CSSRuleList which has a [Symbol.iterator] so it should be iterable too.

In theory the code should work but it throws an error ( "ss.cssRules not iterable" ), is this behaviour intended?

Comment: Works fine for me when testing the exact code you've posted. Please provide a js fiddle/pen that replicates the error.

Comment: I tried it on 3 different tabs(one of which is the one with this question[point being it does not seem to be situation specific but happens for real world examples]). They all reported the same error. Are you using Chrome too?

Comment: Yes, using Chrome.

Comment: Okey, just noticed that it does throw the error when executing the code in the dev console. This seems to be because cssRules can be null or undefined hence not iterable, so add a null-check before the inner for of.

Comment: You are right, you might want to add it as answer so I can select it an upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because cssRules can be `null` or `undefined` hence not iterable, so add a null-check before the inner `for of`.

```
for(var ss of document.styleSheets){
  if(ss.cssRules){
    for(var cssrule of ss.cssRules){
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In typescript due to [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23406) (sadly yet not fixed) I was forced to use following solution

```js
for(let ssIdx=0; ssIdx < document.styleSheets.length; ssIdx++) {  
  let ss = document.styleSheets[ssIdx];

  for(let cssrule of [...ss.cssRules] ) {
    continue;
  }
}
```